# Slicing an Argument on Filter Array?

Tags: javascript, filter, indexof

I have been doing this course for hours on free code camp, however, I found a solution that I do not understand and I am trying to put comments on each line to record as I achieve and understand it for future references and I already understand some lines but I cannot understand some parts of this code:

```
  function destroyer(arr) {
  // let's make the arguments part of the array 
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // this would result into [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3]
   args.splice(0,1); // now we remove the first argument index on the array so we have 2,3 in this example

 // I DO NOT UNDERSTAND THESE CODES BELOW 
  return arr.filter(function(element) { 
  return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
 });

}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

I already check on documentation and I find it hard to understand seems the code in this sample are very different. I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Just to be clear, the code works and you want to know why?

Comment: @amflare yes, I already updated the question. that's my problem.

Comment: What about it do you not understand?

Comment: @Hamms I already updated, I am sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `arr` in the section of code you don't understand refers to the first argument passed to the `destroyer` function; in this case, the array `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`
2. `arr.filter` is using the [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to create a "filtered" version of the array with only those values that pass the "test" defined by `function(element) { return args.indexOf(element) === -1; }`
3. That function uses [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check if the sliced args array (which you correctly identified as being equal to `[2, 3]`) contains the given `element`. Because `indexOf` returns -1 when the element is not found, checking for that value is equivalent to checking that the specified element is NOT in the array

The result of all of this - and the return value of the function `destroy` - will be the array `[1, 1]`, representing a filtered version of the array passed to `destroy` that contains all the values not equal to the other values passed to destroy.

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply but it is not very clear to me as to why do we have to check this code if it is true? return args.indexOf(element) === -1; can you please tell me just a little further..

Comment: That code is the "test" we're using to get a filtered list. We want to get a list composed only of elements that aren't in `args`. If an element is not in `args`, then `args.indexOf(element)` will equal -1, so that's what we're checking.

Comment: thanks I got it now, I was wondering what was happening if it was going to return false if I change the argument on destroyer, I thought we don't need === -1 for it to equal to -1 because of indexOf, which made me confused.

Comment: this would be the last, what does  return args.indexOf(element)===1; is equal to? in the case that I provide..

Comment: are you confused about the nature of the equality operator? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()

Comment: perhaps read the documentation I linked explaining how Array.filter works

Comment: no not with equality, the value of this return args.indexOf(element)===1; in this case, did it return [2,3]? on Array.filter()?

Comment: `return args.indexOf(element) === -1;` returns either `true` or `false`. Read the documentation to understand how that causes the `Array.filter` call to ultimately return `[2, 3]`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

Array.slice is part of the arrays `prototype`; 
`prototype` methods are only accessable on instances of Classes.

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
// [] is JavaScript shorthand for instantiating an Array object.
// this means that you can call:
arr.slice(someArg1);
arry.splice(someArg2);
```